# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, roles, user-roles

im trying to add a default user admin in an .net application while the application is launched (code in startup.cs) but i got this error .
i was following this tuto
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asmabegam/Asp-Net-mvc-5-security-and-creating-user-role/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbCW0.png)

here the function of creating new default user .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njSIl.png)

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB on this Windows 10 (64-bit) machine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a different context than what that example has (ReportContext instead of ApplicationDbContext). Where is ReportContext defined? I don't see a built-in class for it, so I'm guessing that's custom code.

Also, it's generally better to post code as text than images, since it makes it easier to follow the flow and keeps the relevant bits of the question self-contained.

Comment: hi sam. thanks for your time . RapportContext it's the Class DB of the project so it's defined as   "" public ReportContext() : base("name=MyDataBaseName")  "" in the data folder .
im working on class library project